# Javascript executes both if and else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here's my code:

```
var srcArray = ["_images/overlook.jpg","_images/winery_sign.jpg","_images/lunch.jpg","_images/bigSur.jpg","_images/flag_photo.jpg","_images/mission_look.jpg"];
var myImg = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imgIndex = 0;
var status = false;

myImg.onclick = function () {
    if (status) {
        var collage = setInterval(changeSrc,1500);
        status = true;
    } else {
        clearInterval(collage);
        status = false;
    }
}

function changeSrc (){
    myImg.setAttribute("src",srcArray[imgIndex]);
    imgIndex++;
    if (imgIndex == srcArray.length) {
        imgIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to set interval on `changeSrc` when interval is not set and clear interval when interval is set. I saw in Firebug that browser executes first part of `if` and then executes second line of `else` (status = false).

Once interval is set when I click on image it starts another interval on the same image. It basically just runs faster with every click and doesn't stop.

Where's the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You need to declare `collage` the same place you declare `status` - otherwise there's a new `collage` variable each time the "click" handler is invoked, and you'll lose the old timer handles.

Comment: You've mixed up the `status=true` and `status=false`. Notice that in the `if (status)` you're setting `status=true`, when you should be saying `status=false` because it's already true.

Comment: to me it seems like `if (status) {` is never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the image it starts the images rolling over, instant for first, than per timer if you click it stops. I assume that is the desired effect. You don't need the status.

```
var srcArray =     ["_images/overlook.jpg","_images/winery_sign.jpg","_images/lunch.jpg","_images/bigSur.jpg","_images/flag_photo.jpg","_images/mission_look.jpg"],
    myImg = document.getElementById("mainImage"),
    imgIndex = 0,
    tmr;

myImg.onclick = function () {

    // if tmr === undefined, start the rollover.
    if (!tmr) {

       // I call changeSrc() to give instant feedback on first click!
       changeSrc();


       tmr = setInterval(changeSrc,1500);

    // else if tmr has a value stop the rollover, make sure we set tmr to undefined.
    }else{

       clearInterval(tmr);
       tmr=undefined; !IMPORTANT
    } 
}

function changeSrc (){
   myImg.setAttribute("src",srcArray[imgIndex]);
   imgIndex++;
   if (imgIndex == srcArray.length) {
       imgIndex = 0;
}
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/uq8mfLun/2/

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! But I have a question for you, if you don't mind. When I declare tmr it has value "undefined", so why "!tmr" is true?

Comment: And one more thing. After timer stopped once it doesn't start again. tmr returns value "2"...

Comment: OK I have fixed the code and updated my answer. Sorry it was late! It will now restart. When we clear the Interval we must set tmr to undefined.(see updated code and fiddle) Thus when they click again !tmr === undefined and the rollover restarts. I think this answers your question why it was 2.

Comment: I think my answer is the correct solution to the problem and the selected answer is not, as it did not work. I think my answer should be chosen as it solves the problem correctly, works and explains the issues the OP was having.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
myImg.onclick = function () {
    if (status) {
        var collage = setInterval(changeSrc,1500);
    } else {
        clearInterval(collage);
    }
    status = !status;
}
```

In your code, you are initializing status incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Just move collage var out of if statement because when you declare it into if statement this variable only will exist in this scope.

And I don't know why it don't work with bool that's why I change it to number :P I hope someone else can answer that.

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imgIndex = 0;
var status = 1;
var collage;

myImg.onclick = function () 
{
    if(status == 1)
    {
        collage = setInterval(changeSrc,1500); 
        status = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(collage);
        status = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, moving collage var out of if helped

Comment: I think my answer is the correct answer as it works and solves the problem that the question is asking us to solve. It has also been accepted in the comment as correct and working.

Comment: You are right @MartinWebb but what is important here is to help and learn each other.

Comment: I totally agree, My work is just to help others solve problems, and learn myself in doing so. I correct my self if I come across that my intention is not to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the status in `function changeSrc()` instead of doing it in `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works pretty well. You have to change:

```
if (status)
```

by

```
if (status == true)
```

also

```
if (status === true)
```

Explanation: If you write `if(status === true)`, the result will be true only if status is true. But if you write `if(status)`, the result will be true for any status that is different from `false`, `null`, `empty string`, `undefined value`, or `0`.

Hope it useful!

Comment: Although it didn't work (there were also other bugs) it's a very useful information. Thank you ;)